# Show an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have div with an image and anchor tag where anchor element is set to `display:none`.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2015/11/images-from-the-2016-sony-world-pho/s01_130921474920553591/main_1500.jpg?1448476701" Width="200" />
    <center>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="display:none;width:200px;" id="clickMe">Click Me</a>
    </center>
</div>
<script>
    Show() 
</script>
```

Then I'm calling show function to display the anchor tag.

**Show() Function**

```
function Show() {
    alert("HI!");
    $("#clickMe").show();
}
```

But it is not working. How can I display an anchor tag in a function.

[My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y883f7zp/)

Comment: $ is undefined in your fiddle. You didnt refer jquery in the fiddle

Comment: You're mixing pure javascript and jQuery. If you want to use jQuery, you need to include it.

Comment: @GauravMahindra You cant click on something thats not there

Comment: Ask a terrible question, you get terrible answers.

Answer (score 2):

Call show() function on window load event:

```
window.onload = function() {
      Show() ;
};
```

OR use document.ready()

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        Show() ;
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery needs a chance to load before you call a function with jQuery in it.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    Show();
  }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to include `JQuery`. Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myrluk3/y883f7zp/1/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to add jQuery to the fiddle and call the function.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y883f7zp/2/

```
function Show() {
    $("#clickMe").show();
}
Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `jQuery` library before using any of its syntaxes.

After that you need to call the `Show();` method inside `load` as shown below:

**Snippet**:

```
$(function() {
  Show();
});
```

You can also make use of `document.ready()` in-place of `$(function() {..}`

Refer the demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/epnvfmh3/).